# Vector Parametrization of a Hyperbolic Paraboloid and a Plane

Tags: surfaces, parametric

So I need to find the intersection between a hyperboloid ($z=\frac {y^2}{b^2}-\frac{x^2}{a^2}$) and some related plane ($bx+ay-z=0$).

I have tried solving for $z$ and equating the two: $$\frac{y^2}{b^2}-ay-\frac{x^2}{a^2}-bx=0$$

And then trying to find some parameter, which I tried $t=\frac xa$, however that leads to something messy: $$\frac{y^2}{b^2}-ay-t^2-abt=0$$
Any advice? I know the answers already, I just am having a lot of trouble deriving them.

Comment: Eliminating $z$ was a good thing to do. Before you try to parameterize, try completing the square in $x$ and $y$. This will put the equation whose graph you might recognize, which may well help you parameterize it. If you need help doing this, just say so, and I can be a little more explicit.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't parameterize after completing the squares; instead the same parameter $\frac{x}{a}$ creates a very simple solution after.

Comment: Great, I'm glad to hear it worked out. You might like to write up your solution and answer your question here for when someone has a similar questions later.

Answer (score 1):

As recommended, here is my solution for completing the squares. Once you have this form: $$\frac{y^2}{b^2}-ay-\frac{x^2}{a^2}-bx=0$$

You can group the $y$ terms and the $x$ terms. Substituting $u$ for $\frac{y}b$ and $v$ for $\frac{x}a$: $$(u^2-abu)-(v^2+abv)=0$$ $$[(u-\frac{ab}2)^2-\frac{a^2b^2}4]-[(v+\frac{ab}2)-\frac{a^2b^2}4]=0$$ $$(u-\frac{ab}2)^2-(v-\frac{ab}2)^2=0$$

Separate $v$ and $u$ to their own sides, and subsitute $y$ and $x$ back in: $$(\frac{y}b-\frac{ab}2)^2=(\frac{x}a-\frac{ab}2)^2$$

Declaring that your parameter is $t=\frac{x}a$, you end up with a form that is easily solvable for $y$ and $x$, and later $z$.